# Radio Button custom selector is not shown

Tags: android, radio-button, selector, drawable

I created the custom drawable for checked and not checked radio button, however, it is not shown. It seems like the background is omitted. I also tried with setting background as `custom_radio_button.xml`, but it didn't resolve the problem. The background is transparent, even if I delete the `@background` property from `RadioButtonStyle`.

[image: screen]

RadioButton:

```
<RadioButton
  android:id="@+id/both_gender_button"
  style="@style/RadioButton"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="@dimen/big_button_height"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space_l"
  android:checked="false"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:paddingStart="@dimen/space_m"
  android:paddingEnd="@dimen/space_m"
  android:text="@string/women_and_males"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.361"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/woman_gender_button">
```

RadioButtonStyle:

```
<style name="RadioButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
  <item name="android:button">@drawable/custom_radio_button</item>
  <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
  <item name="fontFamily">@font/futura_medium</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
  <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/font_xl</item>
</style>
```

custom_radio_button.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/black_stroke_rectangle" android:state_checked="false" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/black_stroke_rectangle" android:state_focused="false" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/black_stroke_rectangle_white_fill" android:state_checked="true" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/black_stroke_rectangle_white_fill" android:state_pressed="true" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/black_stroke_rectangle_white_fill" android:state_focused="true" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work without setting button to `@null`

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color_default</item>
<item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_radio</item>
<item name="android:layout_marginTop">15dp</item>
<item name="android:buttonTint">@color/selector_radio</item>
```

The `@color/selector_radio` looks like

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/button_dark_normal" />
<item android:state_checked="false" android:color="@color/button_dark_disabled" />
<item android:color="@color/button_dark_disabled"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the selector as a background and set the button to **null**.

```
<style name="RadioButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
    <item name="android:button">null</item>
    <item name ="android:background">@drawable/custom_radio_button</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/futura_medium</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/font_xl</item>
</style>
```

Also set a default drawable for the selector and make it the last item

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/black_stroke_rectangle" android:state_checked="false" />
. . . 
<item android:drawable="@drawable/black_stroke_rectangle_white_fill" android:state_focused="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/black_stroke_rectangle_default" />
</selector>
```